# Eclipse autocomplete (content assist) with jsf2.0, xhtml and primefaces 2.2.RC1

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, primefaces

I use windows 7. I set the ClassPath like this:

D:\EclipseProjects\DLFWD_NEW\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jsf-api.jar;D:\EclipseProjects\DLFWD_NEW\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jsf-impl.jar;D:\EclipseProjects\DLFWD_NEW\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\primefaces-2.2.RC1.jar

And I alse do this:

Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Add (xhtml)

But, it doesn't works.

---

When I use netbeans. I do nothing, but the autocomplete function works well.

Answer (score 2):

First backup your project in other location.

Download Eclipse Helios
and right click on the your Project, goto Properties
go to Project Facets
change the Configuration to JavaServer Faces 2.0 Project
Apply.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:
I have SpringSource Tool Suite 3.0.0 (Eclipse 4.2.0)

```
 Project Properties > Project Facets

 Check: JavaServer Faces. Version: 2.1

 Push Link: Further configuration required...

 Push Icon Button: Download library

 Select: Apache MyFaces o Oracle Mojarra

 Destination folder: I have my own /lib folder into my Project

 Licence: ok
```

and Enjoy!
Content Assist for h: f: and p:

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should add `.xhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

- In `package / project explorer` left-click on project folder.
- Click on `Project Facets` voice on the left
- In the right panel `Convert to faceted form...` should appear. If so, click on it, otherwise skip this step.
- Set up properly your configuration and select `JavaServer Faces`.

Now you should have autocomplete for standard jsf and primefaces libraries.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2.0 Facelets support is [introduced](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192393) in Helios (Eclipse 3.6). For older Eclipse versions, or for more advanced features such as EL autocomplete, you can always use the [JBoss Tools plugin](http://jboss.org/tools). If you're using Glassfish, the [Glassfish Eclipse plugin](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/) also comes with a bit more advanced Facelets support.